# Infinity Gradient

Tags: partial-derivative, infinity

I calculate infinity gradient, but I am not sure is this correct.
[image]

Comment: How can the gradient exist when the function isn't defined there?

Comment: I am not sure, this is my home work. The coordinates are from my student number.

Comment: Thank you very much. May be I need to change the coordinates.

Comment: I agree with Théophile, the most meaningful answer is "the function is not defined there, and no extension of $g$ can be defined continuously on that point, so the gradient does not exist".

Comment: @vili You should apply for a new student number.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I'm sorry, I can't give reputations for now.